# What is the difference between CMDA, GSM, P1000L. and P1000N?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-tab

I'm looking to root (cyanogenmod) a Galaxy Tab I have lying around. Looking on the CMG site, I see that there are 4 different versions: **GSM**, **CDMA**, **P1000L**, and **P1000N**.

What are the differences between these? And how can I tell what version my tablet has?

Comment: The actual model number of your Galaxy Tab can be found in Settings -> About -> Model number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GSM and CDMA refer to the 2G/3G cellular technologies used by phones and tablets.  In USA, AT&T and T-Mobile use GSM, while Sprint and Verizon use CDMA.

GT-P1000L and GT-P1000N are variants of the international Galaxy Tab GT-P1000 version that were released by Samsung for Latin America markets.  Both P1000L and P1000N models have GSM connectivity.  You can find the exact version you have in Settings -> About under the `Model number` section.

In terms of rooting and installing CyanogenMod, you will need to refer to the CyanogenMod wiki for the respective model ([P1000L](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/P1l_Info) or [P1000N](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/P1n_Info)).